# Choose 'in the dim light' or 'under the dim light'

Tags: prepositions

> A: He smoked elegantly in the dim light;
>   B: He smoked elegantly under the dim light.

Between A and B, which one is proper?

Answer (score 2):

It really just depends on where the light is.

> He smoked elegantly in the dim light as the sun went down.
>   He smoked elegantly under the dim street light.